# How do I make a message based communication system between objects?

Tags: javascript, objects, node.js, achievements

Just as I was told [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21502/how-should-i-check-if-a-player-has-completed-an-achievement), I need to make some kind of communication between objects in my game. Mainly, for achievements. How do I do this? My idea was to make every object have an array attached to itself called "messages", and then, when something happens, a message gets pushed there. At the end, I would have a big loop, where I would check messages that each object got, remove them, and act accordingly. I could also have a global array called "messages", and then I would iterate through it, and fire off events in different objects that the messages were sent to (in this case, a message would contain both a message, and some kind of an object ID), and then remove them. Is there a better way? Keep in mind that I'm working in Javascript.

I forgot to mention, we're talking about serverside Javascript running on Node.js, not in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just register events?

Different objects act upon events they listen to, and you can attach some datas to these events (an object like {key: 'value', key2: 'value2'}, for example).

If basic events (click, change, etc) don't satisfy you, you can register custom events. An example of how to do this here : http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/

Edit : heh, even easier in Node.js ! There is an `event` module available. Look at this link : http://venodesigns.net/2011/04/16/emitting-custom-events-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript already uses events internally, so you could leverage that system for your game messages. While there's apparently a W3C specification for custom events, it isn't really supported in all browsers.

Here's an [article](http://www.truerwords.net/articles/web-tech/custom_events.html) that explains a possible implementation of custom events. On the other hand you could simply use a framework like [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/), which has [custom events](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/) implemented and ready to use.

Comment: I forgot to mention thta I'm working on Node.js, not in a browser...

Answer (score 0):

This calls for the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)!
Seems like Node.js already has something like it, called an [EventEmitter](http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html#using-eventemitters).
A similar question was asked in the [Programmers StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74272/the-importance-of-design-patterns-with-javascript-nodejs-et-al).

Hopefully this will start you on the right track!